# Print on one line in python Window

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm not sure how to get multiple outputs from a for loop to print on the same line in a window. I'm using the built in Window function from uagame with python3.x. Here's what the code looks like:

```
for char in a_word:
 if char in user_guess:
  window.draw_string(char+" ",x, y)
 else:
  window.draw_string('_ ',x, y)
 y = y + font_height
```

This keeps displaying as:

```
_
_
_
_
```

And I want it to print as

```
_ _ _ _
```

Any idea how to get each character or _ to display on one line? This is for a WordPuzzle/Hangman type game.

Comment: Can you always use sample data to post and also the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a example, and hopefully you will implement the same to your code.

```
    for i in range(1,10):
        print(i,end=",")
     print()
```

> The output looks like
>
> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

Comment: I can't get end=" " to run within my window.draw_string function.

Answer (score 0):

Define a empty list and append your characters then print all at once

```
a=[]   
    for char in a_word:
         if char in user_guess:
              a.append(char)
         else:
              a.append(char)
    print(a,end=",")
    y = y + font_height
```